# Angular Unit Testing: Access the Observable @Input variable value passed from parent component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, observable

I'm new to testing. I'm writing a unit test for an Input variable which is being set in parent compoent.
The value is an observable which use forkJoin.

parent.component.ts

```
public dataObj$: Observable<{mixType}>;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showChildComponent();
  }
private showChildComponent(): void {
    this.dataObj$ = forkJoin({
      userRoleObj: this.sessionService.sessionInfo$.pipe(take(1)),
      baseCountry: this.intlConfig.country$.pipe(take(1)),
      hasOrgEnabled: this.hasEnable$().pipe(take(1)),
      isAutoApproved: this.onlineService.isAutoApproved$().pipe(take(1)),
    });
  }
```

parent.template.html

```
<child-comp *ngIf="dataObj$ | async as data"  [data]="data" ></child-comp>
```

child.component.ts

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input data!: Observable<mixtype> 
  public settings: any;
  public show = false;
  
constructor() {}
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.settings = this.data; // I want data  to be accessible inside the test case
    this.setValidation();
  }

  public setValidation(): void {
    const isAdmin = this.settings.userRoleObj.profile.type === UI_CONSTS.IS_ADMIN ? true : false;
    if (
      this.settings.isAutoApproved &&
      isAdmin &&
      this.settings.baseCountry === UI_CONSTS.BASE_COUNTRY
    ) {
      this.show = true;
      this.setBulletText();
    } else {
      this.show = false;

    }
  }

  public setBulletText(): void {
    // some code to set the html content
  }

}
```

child.template.html

```
<div *ngIf="show">
    <div> .... </div>
    <h1> ...</h1>
</div>
```

child-component.spec.ts

```
const MOCK_IPD_SETTINGS: {
  baseCountry: string;
  isAutoApproved: boolean;
  userRoleObj: any;
  hasOrgEnabled: boolean;
} = {
 baseCountry: BASE_COUNTRY,
  isAutoApproved: true,
 userRoleObj: {
    profile: {
      type: '2',
    },
  },
 hasOrgEnabled: boolean;
};
describe('ChildComponent', () => {
  let component: ChildComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChildComponent>;

  function setUp({ MOCK_SETTINGS }) {
    component.data = of(MOCK_SETTINGS);
    fixture.detectChanges(); // final change
  }


  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ChildComponent],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      }).compileComponents();
    }),
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InstaPayIpdComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // component.data = of(MOCK_SETTINGS);
    
  });


  it('onClickGetStarted', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.show).toBe(true);
  }));
  it('show open modal',() => {
     setUp({...});
    expect(component.isAutoApproved).toBe(false);
   });
});
```

I'm writing unit test case for the child component. I'm not sure how to access the data or settings object inside the test case.
I'm getting this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it.

The first `fixture.detectChanges()` is when `ngOnInit` is called but the issue is you are setting it to an `of` and not the data itself.

In the HTML it is:

```
<child-comp *ngIf="dataObj$ | async as data"  [data]="data" ></child-comp>
```

The `*ngIf` is unwrapped as an observable but the `[data]` input is what the observable is unwrapped to.

// !! Pay attention to the lines with !!

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InstaPayIpdComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // !! Uncomment line below and remove of(...)
    component.data = MOCK_SETTINGS;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

You should hopefully not face that error any more.

**Edit**

Every time you change `data`, you have to explicitly call `ngOnInit` because we are setting `this.settings = data;` there and we are reading `this.settings`. It is not enough to just do `component.data =`  and expect `this.settings` gets the update. So in short:

```
// We update the data
component.data = /* something new */
// Call ngOnInit so this.settings updates
component.ngOnInit();
// Carry on with your test
```

Comment: Hey , I tried removing of(...) but getting type error in that case, as data is of type observable.

Comment: Change this line: `@Input data!: Observable<mixtype>` to maybe `@Input data!: any` to start with in the component and see if the error goes away. If it does, change the `any` to the appropriate type. I am confident that `data` in the component is not an observable because it is being `| async`'d in the parent component.

Comment: Hey , yeah I check the type I defined is Observable, I have changed it to Patrial and now I'm able to set the data thanks for pointing out.But I'm not able to change the data properites based on the test cases. I have added another test case in my question.

Comment: Hello, check out my edit. I am thinking you need to call `ngOnInit` every time you change `data`.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the solution , I tried with another way, and which did the same thing you mentioned above. I have created a function which is doing all the settings and called detectChange() inside that. and calling the same function inside each test case. (Test case updated)